# Slow down the transition between two slides

Tags: ionic-framework, transition

I'm using $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next() with a custom button to advance a slider. That works fine. However, the documentation at http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/14 suggests that I can include a number for [speed] to change how long the change takes.

I tried with several large numbers, but the transition seems to always take the same amount of time. My goal is to slow down the slide transition between two slides

Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of the next() method or is there another way to achieve this task?

Comment: Welcome to SO again. Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly some versions of ionic have some inconsistency based on documentation. You can try `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(slideNumber, speed)`. And create an index on the scope to control slideNumber, like that:

> var slide = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
>
> var nextIndex = slider.currentIndex()+1;
>
> slider.slide(nextIndex,1000);